# C# . Cannot implicitly convert int to ulong

Tags: c#

I worte the following code in c# and it says cannot implicitly convert type ulong into int what can i do to correct and why did this happen

```
 Random rnd = new Random();

        ulong a;
        ulong input;
        int c1 = 0;
        int c2;  

        a = (ulong)rnd.Next(1, 101);

        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the random number checker.\n" 
            +"You can guess the number. Try and find in how many tries you can get it right. "
            +"\n\t\t\t\tGame Start");

        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your guess");
            input = Console.ReadLine();
            c1 = c1 + 1;
            c2 = c1 + 1;  
            if (input == a)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("CONGRATZ!!!!.You got that correct in "+c1
                    + "tries");
                c1 = c2;

            }
            else if (input > a)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You guessed the number bit too high.try again ");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You guessed the number bit too low ");
            };
        } while (c1 != c2);
```

Whenever i remove that `do{}` part the upper program works fine but as i add it is showed that problem .

Comment: The line `input = Console.ReadLine();` shouldn't compile at all; `Console.ReadLine()` returns a `string`, not a `ulong`.

Comment: Since `ulong` is *unsigned* and `int` is *signed*, it's unclear how to convert *negative* values. Do you really want `ulong`, not, say, `long`?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't believe you that this error appears in the code snippet you show, because there is no assignment or anything like that from an `ulong` to an `int`. _But_ you have some other bugs: `Console.ReadLine()` returns a `string` not a `ulong`, so you can't assign it `input`.

Comment: And normally the compiler tells you the _line_ in which it encounters an error. So it would be helpful if you also tell us which line the compiler complains about.

Comment: @RenéVogt he does compare `int` to `ulong` which does not work as well. However the error should be different for that.

Comment: @Mats391 where? I still don't see it. He only compares `a` to `input` which are both `ulong`, and `c1` to `c2` which are both `int`.

Comment: @RenéVogt you are right. Misstook the `a` for `c` :|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I compiled your code there was only one error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'ulong'
```

In the line

```
input = Console.ReadLine();
```

Everything will be fine if you change it to:

```
input = Convert.ToUInt64(Console.ReadLine());
```

Answer (score 0):

`input = Console.ReadLine();` is the problem. That method returns a `string`, yet your `input` is declared as `ulong`. If you're expecting user to enter a numerical value you need to try to parse it and report and error if not possible. You can do so like this

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter your guess");

            if (!ulong.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter numerical value");
                Environment.Exit(-1);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here: `input = Console.ReadLine()`. `ReadLine` returns string so you can not save it in ulong type. You should do it in this way:

```
    ulong input;
    if (ulong.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out ulong)
    {
        input = input * 2;
    }
    else
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Invalid input!");
    }
```